# Any way of detect mouse coordinate in Excel without using Win API

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find out if it is possible to track the coordinates of the mouse cursor in Excel Worksheet or in User Form WITHOUT using the Win Api?

Ideally, without connecting Avaliable References.

Comment: Userforms have the `MouseMove` event which track the X & Y coordinates. You could use that but it would need to be applied to all the buttons/labels/textboxes etc as well as the main form event. Unfortunately though the coords relay the relative position of the control it's over so you would need to do calculations on top of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Userform controls have the `MouseMove` event (as well as MouseDown/Up) which can track the X & Y coordinates of the mouse. The issue is you need to apply this to all controls that are on the form you wish it to work within. Doing this though, the coordinates given are relative to the control the mouse is over. In order to remedy that, you would need to add calculations for each controls position and add/subtract from the coordinates to get the real position of the mouse on the form.

Here's a little example of it:
[image]

Edit:

I actually just realised you just need to use the `.Left` or `.Top` values of the control and add it to the X or Y value to get the real position relative to the form/frame top left.